# How to save or Export the video with 640 x 640 resolution in IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, avfoundation

I want to **save** a video in **640*640** format.

I am using "**AVAssetExportSession**" to export or save the video.

As per the below instruction, i have a control to change the **presetName**, which actually decides the resolution.

```
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPreset640x480];
```

But the possible available values for presetNames are below and there is no option for 640*640.

NSString *const AVAssetExportPreset640x480;

NSString *const AVAssetExportPreset960x540;

NSString *const AVAssetExportPreset1280x720;

NSString *const AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080;

**Is there any possibilty to export the video with 640*640, using "AVExportSession"?
Or Should i go for some other API?**

Answer (score 2):

If you can use -- AVAssetWriter/WriterInput has a pair of keys [NSString stringWithString:AVVideoScalingModeResizeAspectFill], AVVideoScalingModeKey which will automatically crop your frame to specified output size. Maybe that helps, I do not know about AVExportSession